# ¿Cómo volver a una vista anterior en ASP.NET #?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Necesito que dependiendo de la navegación, una página web me regrese a una vista u otra.

Digamos que hay 3 vistas: Vista 1, Vista 2 y vista 3.
Tanto vista 1 y 2 van a 3, pero la vista 2 tiene una lista, y cuando hago clic en un botón que vaya a la vista 3, la lista se guarde y no perderla, y cuando vuelva de la vista 3 a 2, aparezca la misma lista. El problema es que la lista es dinámica, por lo que preciso guardarla dentro de alguna lista en el controlador o al menos es lo único que se me ocurre. Lo que estaba intentando es tener una lista global `List<model> listaGlobal;`, y cuando busque la lista en la base de datos, a `listaGlobal` la igualo a la lista traída de la base de datos.

Y bueno dependiendo de la vista anterior voy a tener la navegacion 1-3-1, ó 2-3-2. La navegación 1-3-1 ya la tengo.

Lo que fui intentando es, por ejemplo si estoy en la vista 2, guardar en un `ViewData["vistaAnterior"] = "vista2"`, pasarlo al controlador y luego cuando esté en la vista 3 usar un helper:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("VolverVistaAnterior", "Home", new { vista = ViewData["vistaAnterior"] }, FormMethod.Post))
  {
     <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Volver" type="submit"/>            
  }
```

y asi lo recibe el controlador:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult VolverVistaAnterior(string vista)
    {
        if (vista!= "vista2")
        {
            return View("Vista2", listaGlobal);
        }
        return View("Vista1");
    }
```

Pero creo que me la estoy complicando muchisimo, ademas de que no se me está guardando la lista de la vista 2. Debe haber 1000 maneras distintas pero es lo que se me ocurre ahora mismo.

Eh intentado crear una lista global:

```
List<model> listaGlobal;
```

y luego el método "VolverVistaAnterior" quedaría asi:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult VolverVistaAnterior()
{
    try
    {
        if (listaGlobal== null || listaGlobal.Count == 0)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("FiltrarFecha", _entregas);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

`listaGlobal` le asigno un valor cuando busco en la base de datos los elementos necesarios

```
 List<EntregasViewModel> entregasViewModels = new List<EntregasViewModel>();

consulta = "query";
entregasViewModels = SelectPorFecha(consulta);
listaGlobal= new List<EntregasViewModel>();
listaGlobal= entregasViewModels;
```

la lista es traida de la base de datos desde un filtro por fecha de la vista 1, es decir, ingreso un rango de fechas, se buscan los datos en ese rango, y las muestra en una tabla en la vista 2. Entonces cuando hago click sobre una fila, se me redirige a la vista 3, pero no quiero volver a hacer una query a la base de datos, quiero guardarme la tabla en una lista y asi evitar hacer una query

Comment: ¿Y el volver atras del navegador? Tenes que pensar que el usuario tambien puede (y lo hará) navegar desde ahi (ademas del boton en la grilla) . O sea si estoy en la vista 2 y voy a la 3 (y el boton que presiona es el boton de navegador (para atras) porque necesitas hacer algo "especial"? El no volver a hacer la "query"  creo que ahi esta la pregunta especifica no la navegacion. En la web puedes guardar la consulta en el browser (ejemplo localStorage o indexedDb), o realizar una SPA (single page application) con algun framework de frontend

Comment: Gracias! me pongo a investigar los ejemplos que me proporcionaste. Podrías decirme algún ejemplo de cómo usar un LocalStorage para éste caso?